# Why do I get Python Requests Response Error 400

Tags: python, wordpress, http, python-requests

Hi I am trying to use python requests to post to wordpress but i get response 400. Below is my code. What is it am missing? Thanks

```
epoch_time = 1586944173.957986
post = {
    'date': time.ctime(epoch_time),
    'title': 'Api Test question',
    'author': 'symon',
    'content': question,
    'status': 'publish'


}

gradeboosts_url = "https://gradeboosts.com/wp-json/wp/v2"
user = 'aloy'
password = '***************'


creds = user + ':' + password
token = base64.b64encode(creds.encode())
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')}

r = requests.post(gradeboosts_url + '/posts',json=post, headers=headers)

print(r)
```

Comment: Are you able to call the POST from a  tool like post man?

Comment: @balderman yes i am able to post on postman

Comment: good news. Now "ask" postman to prepare the code for you. See https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Comment: Many thanks, I noticed i was creating the post data wrongly; mismatched columns